# Scrape a number from separate spans

Tags: php

I need to scrape the number 622104 from this html

How can I get the number?

```
<div class="numbersBackground">
        <div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl00_numberPanel" class="number">
        <div class="numberWrapper"><span>6</span></div>
    </div><div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl01_numberPanel" class="number">
        <div class="numberWrapper"><span>2</span></div>
    </div><div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl02_numberPanel" class="number">
        <div class="numberWrapper"><span>2</span></div>
    </div><div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl03_commaPanel" class="comma">

    </div><div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl04_numberPanel" class="number">
        <div class="numberWrapper"><span>1</span></div>
    </div><div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl05_numberPanel" class="number">
        <div class="numberWrapper"><span>0</span></div>
    </div><div id="ctl00_mainContent_playersOnlineNumberRepeater_ctl06_numberPanel" class="number">
        <div class="numberWrapper"><span>4</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [**`DOMDocument`**](http://fr.php.net/domdocument) class to parse the HTML string, thanks to its [**`loadHTML`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method, you could use an XPath query *(using the [**`DOMXpath`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class)* to find all `<div>` tag with a `class="numberWrapper"` attribute.

Then, iterate over those, concatenating their content to a variable -- which, at the end of the loop, will contain your number.

For example, you could have this kind of code :

```
$str = <<<HTML
... HERE YOUR HTML ...
HTML;

$number = '';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
if ($dom->loadHTML($str)) {
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query('//div[@class="numberWrapper"]');
    foreach ($results as $div) {
        $number .= $div->nodeValue;
    }
}

var_dump($number);
```

And, as output, you'd get :

```
string '622104' (length=6)
```

You could also use the following XPath query, to make sure you're only working with the `<span>` tags :

```
$results = $xpath->query('//div[@class="numberWrapper"]/span');
```

Here, as the `<div>`s only contain the `<span>`, the result will be the same -- but it might change, in other situations.

*Of course (just to make sure it's said) : Regular Expressions are not the right way to extract informations from an HTML string.*

---

**Edit after the comment :**

If there are other `<div>`s you don't want to take into account, you'll have to find another XPath query -- that matches what you want to extract.

For example, maybe something like this would do the trick :

```
$results = $xpath->query('//div[@class="numbersBackground"]//div[@class="numberWrapper"]/span');
```

Of course, up to you to find out exactly what matches your the structure of your HTML document.

If you want to download the HTML, you have two solutions :

- If [**`allow_url_fopen`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled on your server, you can use [**`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php), passing it the URL as a parameter.
- Else, you'll have to download the HTML content, using, for instance, [**curl**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

As a sidenote, if you get warnings before your HTML is not valid, you'll want to take a look at the [**`libxml_use_internal_errors()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) function ;-)

Comment: +1: "The" correct solution if the input can be trusted to be well-formed. Beat me to it.

Comment: @Jon `DOMDocument::loadHTML` accepts code that's not XML-valid : it works with broken HTML -- if not *too* broken.

Comment: what if there are more divs with a class of number wrapper? and what would I use to direct the script to the webpage rather than entering a string http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/online.aspx

Comment: @Andrew I've edited my answer with some additional informations :-)

Comment: Simpler might be to just extract that snippet from the DOM, then `striptags()` to leave just the numbers. Of course, that assumes the digits in question are the only text nodes in the snippet.